# Let $G$ be a finite group.Let $χ_π$ and $χ_γ$ be group homomorphism from $G$ to $\Bbb C^×$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group.Let $χ_π$ and $χ_γ$ be group homomorphism from $G$ to $\Bbb C^×$.

Then, for arbitrary $h∈G$, how to prove the following ?

> For arbitrary $h∈G$,
>
> $$\sum_{g∈G} χ_π(1)χ_π(g)χ_γ(g^{-1} h) = \sum_{g∈G} χ_π(h)χ_π(g)χ_γ(g^{-1} )$$

$χ_π(1)χ_π(g)χ_γ(g^{-1}) h＝χ_π(h)χ_π(g)χ_γ(g^{-1})$ does not hold in general, bu after summation, we can say the equality, but I can't grasp the mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the mapping $g^{-1}h\mapsto g^{-1}$. then: $g^{-1}\mapsto g^{-1} h^{-1}$.
$\chi_\pi(1)\chi_\pi(g)=\chi_\pi(g)=\chi_\pi(hg)=\chi_\pi(h)\chi_\pi(g)$.
And noticing that the summation goes on $g\in G \to hg\in G \Rightarrow g\in G$.